# can't get text input to work on my simple Sinatra text numbers game

Tags: ruby, forms, sinatra, haml

I have made a simple game in Ruby to help learn it.  Now, I've been trying to implement it in Sinatra, however I cannot get the text input to interact with the 'while' loop.  Can anyone help me see what I'm doing wrong?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'haml'
#use Rack::Session::Pool

module HotColdApp
  def initialize
    guesses = 1
    i = rand(10)
  end

  def play
    "Guess a number from 1 to 10"
    "You have 5 tries"
    "----------"
    guess = gets.to_i
    while guess != i and guesses < 5
      guesses = guesses + 1
      if guess < i
        "too cold"
        guess = gets.to_i
      else guess > i
        "too hot"
        guess = gets.to_i
      end
    end
    if guess == i
       "just right"
    else
       "try again next time"
    end
  end
end

include HotColdApp
  get '/' do
    p initialize
    haml :index
  end

  post '/' do
    guess = params[:guess]
    haml :index, :locals => {:name => guess}
  end

__END__

@@ index
!!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Hot/Cold
  %body
    %h1 hOt/cOld
    %p
    Guess a number from 1 to 10. You have 5 tries.
    %form{:action => "/", :method => "POST"}
    %p
    %input{:type => "textbox", :name => "guess", :class => "text"}
    %p
    %input{:type => "submit", :value => "GUESS!", :class => "button"}
    %p
```

Comment: Don't you need to add `@` to your instance variables?

Comment: You never call the play method and if you did the play method wouldn't make any sense in this case.

Comment: Also, your haml is in correct. It outputs <form></form> instead of embedding the buttons inside of the result. You need to indent the inputs.

Comment: the Haml does output both the form and the buttons though.  Are you saying I need to somehow rework the play method?

Comment: You need to do more than output them. They need to be between <form>...</form>. Right now you have form <form></form><textfield><submit> which doesn't do anything. I also fixed your post in my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this does exactly what you're looking for but it does play the game. Some things to notice: I changed the play method. Using a while loop and gets doesn't really make much sense. Instead I grabbed the parameter and passed to play while keeping count of the guesses. I indented the form because you weren't nesting submit or the text field inside of the form. I recommend you look at the source of your page after you generate with haml. It didn't see that you totally understood what was going on. This should give you more than a few steps to get ahead with.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'haml'
#use Rack::Session::Pool

module HotColdApp
  def initialize
    @guesses = 5 
    @i = rand(10)
  end 

  def play(guess)
    guess = guess.to_i
    if(@i != guess && @guesses > 1)
      @guesses -= 1
      if guess < @i
        return "#{@guesses} left. Too cold"
      else guess > @i
        return "#{@guesses} left. Too hot"
      end 
    elsif(@i != guess && @guesses == 1)
      return "You lose!"
    elsif(@i == guess)
      return "You win!"
    end 
  end 
end

include HotColdApp
  get '/' do
    p initialize
    haml :index
  end 

  post '/' do
    guess = params[:guess]
    @result = play(guess)
    haml :index, :locals => {:name => guess}
  end 

__END__

@@ index
!!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Hot/Cold
  %body
    %h1 hOt/cOld
    %p
    Guess a number from 1 to 10. You get 5 tries.
    %form{:action => "/", :method => "POST"}
      %p
      %input{:type => "textbox", :name => "guess", :class => "text"}
      %p
      %input{:type => "submit", :value => "GUESS!", :class => "button"}
    %p
    %p= @result
```

Comment: Oh, i understand now.  thanks very much.  I was repurposing it from a CLI learning program I made today.  I'll keep tweaking it now to further understand things.